# How can I flush/align Python Plotly axis ticks with graph border?

Tags: python, plotly

I am having some frustration trying to figure out (searching, trial and error) how to flush Plotly axis and the zero tick (see picture below)

here is my code:

```
import plotly.go_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=label,
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(size=10),
        opacity=0.5,
    )
)
fig.update_layout(
    font_family="Arial",
    template="simple_white",
    title={"x": 0.5, "y": 0.9, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
    yaxis=dict(mirror=True, ticks="outside", range=[0, 1]),
    xaxis=dict(mirror=True, ticks="outside"),
    legend=dict(
        yanchor="top", xanchor="right", borderwidth=0.5, x=0.995, y=0.99
    ),
)
```

[Snippet of unflushed portion]

[image: 1]

Comment: `fig.update_yaxes(rangemode="tozero")` This will make the y-axis start from zero, but in reality it is not starting from zero, as you pointed out. I checked what is affecting it, and it seems to be the theme, so try setting the theme to 'none' or selecting something else.

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners. Changing the theme made it better. I also played with the tick width (made it thicker) and that also kinda helped. I might open it up as an issue to plotly on their github

Comment: If you get really desperate, you can tinker with adjusting the number in `fig.update_xaxes(position=0.004)`. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to get the size of the plotting area in pixels. If you had that, along with your xaxes linewidth, you could calculate the exact number to use here.

Comment: Or, I suppose you could hide the xaxis, and instead draw a horizontal line on your plot at x=0. But again, this isn't _really_ what you were looking for.